# Is there a reason in sink dishwashers are not available in Europe?

Tags: dishwasher

To avoid spamming for a specific product, I am inserting a picture from a design case study -- I do not know where to buy this one or what it is even called.

[image]

But similar ones are readily available in China, Singapore, India, United States ... but not Europe. I found some tests for one from 2009 so it used to exist here.

Is there a reason for this? Does the design have inherent faults? Is there a regulation against it? I am very surprised about this because the space savings look great.

Comment: The only machines I've seen of this sort in the US are really not worth buying. There may be exceptions, and/or something better might exist elsewhere.

Comment: How does it even save space?  You'd need the space in front of it to unload it anyway so why not just have the standard one?  Are you planning a kitchen with a super narrow walkway?  You can get drawer dishwasher which pull out and take less room than a standard.  The top one looks like it would be painful to load and unload and is so specialized you'd have to replace your sink and counter if you ever switch it out.  I am on my 3rd dishwasher and still have the same sink in 28 years.

Comment: Any space savings in the design pictured are probably wiped out by what looks to me to be a big inconvenience - the dishwasher lid is also the part of the sink unit generally used as a draining board, meaning that in order to access the dishwasher, you cannot have any dishes drying, and you would have to move any drying rack. A large part of kitchen design is maximising usable worktop space, which this design fails to do. (and it saves no space compared to a half-width dishwasher)

Comment: "Available in the US" - are you defining that as "easily found on Amazon, eBay and other sites which mirror Amazon and eBay (like Sears or Walmart)?  That hardly counts; that's true for everything.  You can even get British electric showers on Amazon/eBay - even reputable brands!  And I assure you, electric showers are **not** a US thing.   A better test would be "does Home Depot/Lowes stock 5 models of it?"   Their stock is visible on homedepot.com or lowes.com.  Though if your IP address is overseas you'll be shopping the Maine or Tacoma, WA store.

Answer (score 1):

In many European countries, when you move you take all appliances with you. Sometimes this also includes the kitchen cabinets and flooring.

A dishwasher built in the sink would for most people not be moveable, unless you took everything *including* the kitchen sink.

Hence I suppose people deem it a throw away investment. Of course, there could be a market for furnished short term / vacation rentals.

If you ask about regulations, I don't believe anything prohibits it, and the answer is probably related to post-war & frugal cultural preferences.

In this frame of mind, a small on-the-counter dishwasher would be a more feasible option.